# How many trie's does Ethereum have?

Tags: state-trie, merkle-patricia-tries

Did I miss any trie below and get things right?

- **Transaction** tries, one per block, root hash included in the block header
- **Transaction receipt** tries, one per block, root hash included in the block header
- **Storage** tries, one per account, root hashes across accounts used to build the state trie
- **State** trie, one per world state, updated root hash included in the block header

Comment: What is the difference between the two first trie that you have mentioned?

Comment: A transaction is a message that gets included in the blockchain. A (transaction) receipt is metadata indicating effects of a transaction (things like gas used, logs)—see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/16541/136.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds correct to me.

Referring to the graphical interpretation of the descriptions in the Yellow Paper, your 4 tries are shown in the "Information required to derive block header" section.

The picture exactly matches your descriptions.

[image: Ethereum as a picture]

Comment: So is it correct to assume that a separate trie is built from scratch for the transactions & receipts with every block? Or, is there just one transaction trie that's keyed by the transaction (hash?), only a small subset of which is included in each block?